# формирование таблицы через поиск в excel

Tags: excel

возможно ли реализовать такой поиск в результате которого формируется таблица?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно формулами, можно макросом. Можно установить автофильтр и фильтровать на месте по нужной фамилии.

Comment: Не подскажите какой-то мануал, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Выделить таблицу, вкладка *Данные-Фильтр*